# SCSS constants across stylesheets (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'd have a long list of colors that I want included with every scss file in /app/assets/stylesheets. I tried including it in application.css.scss, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What to do:**

- Create a `colors.scss` file with the colors you want accessible to `layouts/application.html.erb`.
- Place `colors.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets/partials/shared`. This is not required. I just like to be organized.
- Within application.css.scss include the file `@import "partials/shared/colors".` You might prefer a different structure, but no need to append the file extension the asset pipeline knows.
- (**Optional**) Remove the `require_tree` directive. Removing this directive and relying on `@import` enables your preprocessed stylesheets (e.g. *.css.scss) is a way to load styles in the order they appear.

**What you just did:**

The `stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` declared in `application.html.erb` is looking for `application.css.scss` by default. We've told the Asset Pipeline to use it in any view that uses the `application.html.erb` template. Now, each view will have access to the colors you specify.

More resources:
There are several deeper dives into the AP. I recommend you check them out. Here are some I found helpful.

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

[Secrets of the Asset Pipeline](http://speakerdeck.com/u/metaskills/p/secrets-of-the-asset-pipeline)